# move/copy files under OSX using unix functions

Tags: c, macos, file, unix, copy

I would like to copy (or move) files under Mac OS X as fast as possible while keeping the control of the copy process:
- If a target file already exists, have a way to ask if (overwrite, skip, rename), even if it is a subdirectory of a copied directory.
- Have progress of the copy process (remaining time, sizes, ...)

Thanks for your help

Comment: This question already has a close vote on it (I didn't do it).  Is this a programming question or a how-to-do-on-the-command-line question?  I'd recommend migrating this question to superuser.com.

Comment: it is a programming question, not a command line question.

Comment: why do you want to use UN*X functions for this?  I can tell you about `system` and `NSTask`, but if you want to track progress and ask users about overwriting, skipping, renaming, you really really need to do this with native MacOS calls.  What language are you writing your app or command line tool in?

Comment: Can you specify more exactly what your problem is? The file handling? Connecting progress to a progress bar? Some other user interface related problem?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann it is an objective-c cocoa application. I am ok to use cocoa functions but I didn't found any able to ask for overwrite and showing progress

Comment: Your requirements are contradictory.  If you want the process to be as fast as possible, then you do not want user interaction.

Comment: @WilliamPursell user interaction should not happens in most of the cases.

Answer (score 2):

A good way of learning how to do this, is by looking at existing code for open source projects. A tool that comes to mind that does all the checking you are talking about (check if existing, progress, etc) is rsync.

For instance, if you want to learn how to report the progress back to the user, check the source for where it parses the "--progress" argument, see what functions are invoced as a result of this, and try to understand. In this case you will end up in `progress.c` where the meat of the file is a function with the following definition

```
/**
 * @param ofs Current position in file
 * @param size Total size of file
 * @param is_last True if this is the last time progress will be
 * printed for this file, so we should output a newline.  (Not
 * necessarily the same as all bytes being received.)
 **/
static void rprint_progress(OFF_T ofs, OFF_T size, struct timeval *now,
                int is_last)
```

Normal C and portable across a range of operating systems - not just OS X.
This might not be a direct answer to your question, but one that might get you further :)

[Source code for rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/rsync-3.0.9.tar.gz)

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, so you ***can*** use Objective C methods.  Goody!

Consider [`[[NSFileManager defaultFileManager] copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtURL%3atoURL%3aerror%3a).  I've linked the documentation at Apple for you.

Take a look at the "discussion" section for that method and it tells you how to handle overwriting and renaming (i.e. when errors are thrown, call delegate methods and you can bring up your own "Want to overwrite?" alerts, etc.).

This method works for 10.6 & newer.  There's an older method which will work with older OSX versions.  If you need it and can't find the name of it, let me know and I'll edit this answer to provide more detail.

Comment: How do you get copy progress using this function?

Comment: count the number of items you're going to move / copy before you begin the operation and then you can use an increment counter to move a progress bar in a window or view you bring up.

Comment: I would like to do the same whithing the copy of a large file.

Comment: Then look at the source code for rsync. It does what you want. And really, it is not exactly rocket science to think of a way to do it yourself either :-)